# Почему тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему тут стоит запятая перед И: "Но на близкой дистанции доверчивы, и даже слишком"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом предложении используется присоединительная конструкция в виде частицы даже с союзом И - " и даже". Перед сочинительным союзом присоединительной конструкции нужно ставить запятую.